# VS 2010 migration issue – XSD.EXE can’t process Framework 4.0 assemblies

Tags: visual-studio-2010, xsd, migration

In VS 2008 / SDK 6.0 I used the /t option of the XSD utility to automatically generate XSD files from existing assemblies / classes. With VS 2010 **and** SDK 7.0 this isn’t working any longer, because the XSD.EXE can’t process the new Framework 4.0 assemblies. It stated to be a Framework 2.0 tool and can’t process assemblies of newer runtimes.

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A closer look and there is the answer to my own question:

There are two XSD tools coming with VS 2010!

Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/bin/xsd.exe – the XSD tool for the older frameworks

Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.0A/bin/NETFX 4.0 Tools/xsd.exe – the XSD tool for framework 4.0 assemblies

The first time I take the wrong version :-)

Comment: +1 Got as far as the bin folder and told everyone that it had to be a 2.0 assembly. That'll teach me :)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using xsd.exe that came with VS 2008 to create xsd files for .net 4 assemblies.  Should you not be using the version that came with VS 2010